# Are there any complex sklearn models with partial_fit or similar for online learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am looking for a Python online learning/incremental learning algorithm of 'reasonable' complexity.

In Scikit-learn I have found a few algorithms with the `partial_fit` method, namely `['BernoulliNB', 'GaussianNB', 'MiniBatchKMeans', 'MultinomialNB', 'PassiveAggressiveClassifier', PassiveAggressiveRegressor', 'Perceptron', 'SGDClassifier', 'SGDRegressor']`

All these algorithms form simple decision boundaries as far as I can see. Do we have out-of-the-box online algorithms somewhere in Python which can model more complex decision boundaries?

Correction: As noted below K-means does of course not have a simple decision boundary. What I was looking for was supervised algorithms capable of, e.g., XOR.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "more complex decision boundaries".  It's not clear to me what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: For instance, XOR boundaries

Comment: Furthermore, I was particularly interested in supervised models.

Comment: Just want to add that the current version if this is a good question and should not be down voted. As far as having incremental/updatable and preferred complexity and fuzzy boundaries, the best I can think of is neural nets since they can be updated from a previously trained model. (not sure if sklearn can). Hope that helps the next person who finds this.

Answer (score 1):

One general approach is to combine a **Linear-Classifier** with some **Kernel-Approximation** techniques, e.g.:

- SGD-based SVM/Logistic Regression with:

  - [Nystroem](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.kernel_approximation.Nystroem.html)
  - [RBFSampler / Random Kitchen Sinks](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.kernel_approximation.RBFSampler.html#sklearn.kernel_approximation.RBFSampler)

Just build up a [pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) and you are still able to use `partial_fit`.

One more remark (regarding your list of algorithms): KMeans or KNearestNeighbor does not form a linear decision-boundary!

Comment: Yes, you are right about K-means (I was thinking of supervised algorithms). Regarding KNearestNeighbor: It does not seem to have a partial_fit

Comment: Hi @sascha, could you please elaborate? (1) All Kernel-Approximation that you've mentioned doesn't have `partial_fit`. (2) `Pipeline` also doesn't have `partial_fit`.